# Unexpected behaviour in really simple google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So here is my google apps script without the block comment on top:

```
function GET_POSITION(game,position) {
  defaultsheets=['Stats','Games','Calculations'];
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    name=defaultsheets.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1;

    return false;
    if(name)
    {
      name='test';
    }
  });
  return name;
}
```

Yes I know, this is a weird script and it does not do anything.That is because I kept changing it trying to find out why it would not work.

But that is not the problem. I would expect this script to return false.
It does not, it returns true. But when i remove the "return false" it still wont run the if statement (it just keeps returning True).

Meaning:

- return false gets ignored?
- name is equal to true, but when doing if(name), the if statement is not executed.

Putting name="test" at the beginning of the sheet will make the function return "test".

I have no idea why this script is functioning this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, haha, this *is* a weird script.  When I first looked at it, I thought, how could this even run without a compiling error?  The variable `name` is being called outside the scope of a closure, the rest of the function shouldn't know anything about it, it would give an undeclared variable error.

Then I saw that you're not using `var` to initialize your variable `name`.  That makes `name` behave like a global constant.  That will give you unexpected behavior certainly.  There is just never a good reason to do that.

[Declaring variables without var keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword)

Another thing is that only that anonymous function is returning false.  Then it jumps out and returns `name`, which has been set to true.

[What are Closures and Callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks)

And, I have to ask, why are you using ALL_CAPS to name a function?

Comment: ah, of course, completely forgot that I made a function inside of the foreach. Thanks! As for your question, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions all google sheets functions are in all caps,