# Creating instance with an association in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com), I've created two models: `User` and `Login`.

Users can have more than one Login, but a login must have exactly one user, which means a Login cannot be saved without a User ID.

How do I `.create` a Login with a User association all in one swoop?

**Current Code (Doesn't Work)**

```
// Set up the models
var User = sequelize.define('User', {});
var Login = sequelize.define('Login', {});
Login.belongsTo(User, {
  onDelete: 'cascade',
  foreignKey: {
    field: 'userId',
    allowNull: false,
  }
});

// Create the instances
var user = User.create().then(function() {

  // THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO SET THE ASSOCIATION
  var login = Login.create({
    userId: user.get('id')
  });

)};
```

The above results in `SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: UserId cannot be null`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Assuming you have the right association between users and login,
you can just create a user including a login:

```
User.create({
   name: "name",
   Login: {...}
},{
   include: Login
})
```

you can find more information here:
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/

Comment: @slifty this should be marked as the correct answer as it's more succinct.

Comment: The link is outdated. I believe the current one (for now at least) is: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations

Comment: Is there a way to do this for bulkCreate()?

Comment: I don't know, but have you tried it? Would be interesting. If it doesn't work you could use a transaction...

Comment: @xabitrigo your link is outdated as well.

Comment: @testing_22 You are right, the current one is https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/

Answer (score 19):

First of all you need to setup the relations in both ways, like this:

```
// Set up the models
var User = sequelize.define('User', {});
var Login = sequelize.define('Login', {});

// Set the correct associations
User.hasMany(Login, {})
Login.belongsTo(User, {});
```

Then, you need to properly get the instances returned by the promises:

```
// Create the instances
User.create({}).then(function(newUser) {
    // now you can use newUser acessors to create the login
    return newUser.createLogin({});
).then(function(newLogin){
    // newLogin
}).catch(function(error){
    // error
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matheus.  For folks looking at this from the future: the big mistake I was making is that .create returns a promise, not a user (.build returns a user).

Comment: This just helped my life! why does the documentation say `User.set<Object>()` instead of `User.create<Object>()`??
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#associating-objects

Answer (score 6):

In your `.then`, the callback receives the model instance created by the previous call. You need to specify the argument inside the callback function.

```
var user = User.create().then(function(user) {

  // THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO SET THE ASSOCIATION
  var login = Login.create({
    userId: user.get('id')
  });

  return login

}).then(function(login) {
    // all creation are complete. do something.
});
```

Also something important I would like to point out is your missing `var` statements! Those are important but not related to this question. See [Declaring variables without var keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword)

Comment: Thank you for the var callout!  I blame the fact that I was slamming code together to try to understand how to use sequelize!  (updated my example to reflect better practice).  The big issue that caused confusion for me is that .create() returns a promise (while .build returns a user).

Comment: Technically both .create() and .build() returns a `promise`. `instanceof userByBuild // Promise` :)

Comment: Darn!  Well I have no excuse then!  (and good to know for future)

Comment: @Calvintwr I have problem with this too! When I used `userId: user.id` it doesn't work and throw the error. After I changed it to `UserId: user.id` it works. Do you know about the issue? please help!!!

Comment: it's probably because "UserId" is the field name of your User model. If you don't define the id field of your model, it will just use the name the model and add "Id" behind

Answer (score 5):

An Update to @Arwed Mett's answer

```
//Create Association Alias or just setting association alias by using 'as' keyword will also work
Login.User = Login.belongsTo(User);

User.create({
 name: "name",
  Login: {...}
}, {
  include: [{
    association: Login.User
  }]
});
```

Refrence link - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations

Answer (score 2):

For those like me who were trying to create an instance of a model including another instance, like:

```js
var login1 = await Login.create(...);
var user1 = await User.create({
    Login: login1
}, {
    include: Login
});
```

You can't because this method is used to embed an instance (Login) which is not already existing and that will be created at the parent instance (User) creation level.

So, if you want to embed an already existing Login in the newly created User, do instead:

```js
var login1 = await Login.create(...);
var user1 = await User.create({
    loginId: login1.get('id')
}, {});
```

Comment: bear in mind that, depending on how you have everything set up, you might have to capitalize `loginId` (as in: `LoginId: login1.get('id')`)

Answer (score 1):

You have association between User an Login with constraint allowNull at false. You must create Login before User or set allowNull at true in model and the table to DB (LoginId Null constraint)

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {});
var Login = sequelize.define('Login', {});
Login.belongsTo(User, {
  onDelete: 'cascade',
  foreignKey: {
    field: 'userId',
    allowNull: false,
  }
});
```

Solution

```
Login.create({
   username: "username",
   User: {...}
},{
   include: User
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue recently!
I have a typo mistake with the foreignKey config. Use `field` instead of `name` caused the issue.

The change below will fix it.

```
{
    foreignKey: {
       name: 'userId',
       allowNull: false,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extra you could also nest your creation to be even more effective and concise.

```
  // Set up the models
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {});
    var Login = sequelize.define('Login', {});
        ...


    User.create({
       name: "name",
       Login:
            {
            users: {..i.e several users if a user belongs to another user..}
            }
        },{
       include:{
      model: Login,
      include: User //nested model.Create
         }
    })
```

as seen here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7252