# Modified deepEqual function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

I was looking at the `deepEqual` comparison function from the *Eloquent Javascript* exercises.  I thought I could make an improvement on the suggest solution by moving the `if` statement that checks for the object existence and value equality check to the first `for..in` loop rather than the second.

*My reasoning was that it would allow the check to fail earlier if the objects didn't have matching properties or their values were different rather than waiting to do so in the second loop.*

***The change did not work***.  [This jsbin demonstrates the issue](https://jsbin.com/sucolufike/edit?js,console), and this is the code:

```
function deepEqual(a, b){
  if(a === b) return true;
  if(a === null || typeof a !== "object" ||
     b === null || typeof b !== "object")
    return false;

  var pA = pB = 0;
  //console.log('OBJECT detected vals:',a,b);
  for(var p in a){
    pA++;
    //console.log('pA:'+pA, p, a, (p in b));
    // MOVED THE IF STATEMENT INTO THIS LOOP INSTEAD OF THE
    // SECOND LOOP BELOW
    if(!(p in b) || !deepEqual(a[p], b[p]))  
      return false;
  }

  for(var p in b){
    pB++;
    //console.log('pB:'+pB, p, b, (p in a));
    //if(!(p in a) || !deepEqual(a[p], b[p]))
      //return false;
  }

  return pA === pB;
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true WORKS
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false WORKS
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true, DOES NOT WORK, LOGS OUT FALSE...?
```

Commenting out the console.log call in snippet should render the following output:

```
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
OBJECT detected vals: Object {here: Object, object: 2} Object {here: Object, object: 2}
pA:1 here Object {here: Object, object: 2} true
OBJECT detected vals: Object {is: "an"} Object {is: "an"}
pA:1 is Object {is: "an"} true
pB:1 is Object {is: "an"} true <-- why is this being called here, pA loop hasn't finished???
pA:2 object Object {here: Object, object: 2} true
pB:2 here Object {here: Object, object: 2} true
pB:3 object Object {here: Object, object: 2} true
```

> **From what I can see, the `for..in` for the `b` argument starts early here and affects the later running of the loop with correct
>   values.
>
>  What have I missed?**

---

**The way I think it *should* work**

As I understand it, the 3rd log *should* run as follows:

CALL:

**`deepEqual({here: {is: "an"}, object: 2},{here: {is: "an"}, object: 2})`**

- `(a === b)`→ `false`,
- `a` and `b` are objects, continue
- set `pA` and `pB` to 0
- start `for..in` loop

  1. `pA` is 1, `p` is `here`

     - `here` is in `b` so have to CALL:
     - **`deepEqual({is: "an"}, {is: "an"})`**
     - *they're both objects so go:*
     - start `for..in` loop

       - `pA` is 1, `p` is `is`

         - `here` is in `b` so have to CALL:
         - **`deepEqual("an", "an")`**
     - <<<<<<<<<<<< RETURN TRUE!!!
     - **`if` fails, start next iteration of loop**:
  2. `pA` is 2, `p` is `object`

     - `object` is in `b` so have to CALL:
     - **`deepEqual(2, 2)`**
     - *they're both objects so go:*
     - start `for..in` loop

       - `pA` is 1, `p` is `is`

         - `here` is in `b` so have to CALL:
         - **`deepEqual(a['is'], b['is'])`**
     - <<<<<<<<<<<< RETURN TRUE!!!
- At this point `pA` is 2
- All that's left to do is, iterate over props in b
- `pB` should be 2

Return `(pA === pB)`, which is the same as `return 2===2`, which is `return true`

It's currently logging out `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been bitten by JavaScript's [Implicit Globals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Implicit_globals_and_outer_function_scope)

The problem is this line:

```
var pA = pB = 0;
```

When deconstructed into multiple lines, it looks like:

```
pB = 0;
var pA = pB;
```

Which means `pB` is not getting declared with `var` and is thus a **global** variable, not a variable local to `deepEqual`. This means it preserves its value through calculations and hence has the wrong value.

Your function returns `false` because `pB` for the top object level with 2 properties ends up with a value `3` instead of `2` because it remembers its count from the inner level, which had 1 property `{ is: "an" }`. The other two tests work because they only check a single level of properties.

If you make `pB` a local variable everything works:

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;
  if (a === null || typeof a !== "object" ||
    b === null || typeof b !== "object")
    return false;

  // make both variables local
  var pA = 0;
  var pB = 0;
  for (var p in a) {
    pA++;
    if (!(p in b) || !deepEqual(a[p], b[p]))
      return false;
  }

  for (var p in b) {
    pB++;
  }

  return pA === pB;
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
```

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword) worth checking out.

Comment: Ahah! Thanks! I had an inkling that it was something to do with that. I think I must have been trying to do this: `var pA, pB = pA =0;`. Is my reasoning that moving the`if` condition to the first loop sound?

Comment: @Pineda You're welcome. As far as having that `if` condition in either loop, it won't really change anything in terms of general (based on worst case)  efficiency. Your change could help for some specific cases but it then makes other cases less efficient. Essentially what you did was make `pA` more important that `pB` but if anybody passes the arguments in reverse than the initial unchanged approach would be better.