# JavaScript scope of variable

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var change8 = function()
{
    console.log(a);
    console.log("End of function");
    a = 10;
}

change8();
```

Return Reference Error

```
var change8 = function()
{

    console.log(a);
    console.log("End of function");
    var a = 10;
}

change8();
```

Return Undefined

Why first code return Reference Error But Second code return undefined ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Answer (score 4):

Javascript does something called hoisting, in which before it executes, it looks for `var` declarations and creates those variables. Since you used `var a` in the second, it creates the variable, but it isn't defined when used. In the first one, `a` doesn't exist until you create it, so it's a reference error.

Comment: This is actually the best explanation. Thanks

Comment: window.a; console.log(a); Return Reference error Global variable not assigned value global variable is not created?

Comment: Where are you seeing that? I just ran it in the web console and got no error

Comment: window.a; console.log(a); Declare global variable but  but not assigned value

Comment: Just calling window.a does not create it

Answer (score 1):

It is called [`variable hoisting`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp). In JS declared variables are actually hoisted (moved up) to top of the scope they bound to, so in your case they are moved up to beginning of your function. In the second example `a` is treated as it is actually declared at the top of method before any of the assignments, then assigned to `10` later. So when you print `a` the variable is defined but its value is not assigned yet.

```
var change8 = function()
{
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    console.log("End of function");
    a = 10;
}
```

But in the first example a is not  defined with `var` keyword so `a` will be treated as a global variable and won't be available until the assignment. Thus when it is called before the assignment the error will occur.

For understanding declaring variables with `var` keyword check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword)

Comment: window.a  = 10;

console.log(a);
Return Reference error 
Global variable not assigned value global variable is not created?

Comment: You attached `a` to `window` which is the global object, then js search through hierarchy when you `log` `a` and find it on `window` object thus prints it. Since you have attached it to `window` object before calling it you don't get an exception, if you try otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: create globar variable but not assigned value  look like
window.a;
console.log(a)

Comment: why bring window.a to the discussion, it will only complicate the answer. hoisting is part of js ecosystem and will exist in non-browser environments like node too.

Comment: I think your "ES 6" (i.e. ECMAScript 2015) inference is incorrect and you're confusing it with strict mode. Do you have a reference? Only variable declarations are "hoisted".

Answer (score 1):

```
var change8 = function()
{
    console.log(a);
    console.log("End of function");
    a = 10;
}

change8();
```

variable `a` is assigned undefined in the global context since [JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Consider the same code as -

```
var a; // is = undefined
       // in global context

var change8 = function()
{
    console.log(a);
    console.log("End of function");
    a = 10;
}

change8();
```

Hence you'll get - *Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined*

This won't happen in 2nd code because you've explicitly declared your variable with `var`. Read more about hoisting [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: "*variable a is hoisted to the top*" No it isn't, undeclared variables are created as properties of the global object when the code assigning to them is executed, not before. So called "hoisting" occurs with declarations, and the variable is initialised to undefined so the comment "isn't defined yet" is also incorrect.

Comment: @RobG my confusion stems from 'variables in js have function level scope' so I thought (till now) that scope will still be limited to that particular function and it will be hoisted inside it only.

Comment: *JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations*

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal—correct. Functions are parsed before execution begins (hence early syntax errors), but function bodies are only processed once control enters them (i.e. the function is called), until then they sit passively doing nothing but taking up space. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is because,in the first snippet you are using 'a' before declaring it with var, thus 'a' belongs to the global scope, hence a reference error when you call your method because 'a' will only be in the global scope when the third line 'a = 10' was executed

In the second one 'a' is undefined because it is being used before it was declared using var, albeit it is still in the function's scope, when function is called during run-time, the first line 'console.log(a)' does not know 'a'