# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined - knockout observableArray

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

When I click this button, an object is created and added to the array which is reflected in UI. Next when I click this button again I get an error **"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"**. What could possibly be the issue? Since the context seems fine otherwise it wouldn't have called the appropriate function in Rule class.

**html code**

```
<div data-bind="with: formatterVM">
    <div data-bind="with: currentRule">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: conditions">
            <li data-bind="html: x"></li>
            <li data-bind="html: y"></li>
        </ul>
        <button data-bind="click: addCondition">Click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS/Knockout code

```
function ReportsVM() {
    self = this
    self.formatterVM = new FormatterVM()
}

function FormatterVM(){
    self = this
    self.rules = ko.observableArray()
    self.currentRule = ko.observable(new Rule())
}

function Rule(){
    self = this
    self.conditions = ko.observableArray()
    self.addCondition = function(){
        self.conditions.push(new Condition(2,3))
    }
}

function Condition(x,y){
    self = this
    self.x = ko.observable(x)
    self.y = ko.observable(y)
}
// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new ReportsVM());
```

Working JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/etppe937/

**Update**
It was an issue with the scope of the `self` variable. We need to use `var` keyword in order to not let the variable have a global scope. JSFiddle has been updated.

Comment: [declaring-variables-without-var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword)

Comment: Can you be more specific with your answer? Which variables need to be declared with 'var' keyword?

Comment: Well all of them should be, but in your example there's only one undeclared variable, and that's "self".

Comment: if your code is trying to access the `property` push instead of trying to leverage the `function` push, then `conditions` is probably not the type you are expecting it to be. And actually, looks like `conditions` is `undefined` to start with, therefore there is no accessible `function` called `push` on that _object_.

Comment: @JasonSpake Great! This has solved my issue. Thanks for your help!