# javascript code raising warning in jshint.com "Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics"

Tags: javascript

The javascript code:

```
for (j = 0; j < array.length; j ++) {
    if (
        array[j].some(
            function(word) {
                return word.indexOf(array1[i]) > -1;
            }
        )
    ) {
        makeSomething();
    }
}
```

produces a `Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (array1)` warning in `jshint.com`.

Actually it works.

Is it really problematic?

How should it be written?

Comment: You can declare that function outside the for scope and achieve the same result while being more clear

Answer (score 2):

No this is not a problem. The warning is missing the reasoning:

If the callback would be called back asynchronously, then it would be confusing:

```
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i); // guess what this logs
      });
  }
```

But you should really *always declare variables* and *always use `let` or `const` for that*:

```
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j ++) {
```

that will make the warning go away, and will also fix the example above (and it avoids a [probably confusing implicit global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword)).

Comment: I cannot understand clearly... in my example shoul I change `for (j = 0` to `for (let j = 0`?

Comment: .... jshint gives a warning with `array1`, how can the `let j` change something? actually, adding the `let`, jshint keeps giving me the same warning

Comment: But now you can ignore it without feeling bad :)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare that function outside the for scope and achieve the same result while avoiding the warning.

```
const functionName = function(word) {
    return word.indexOf(array1[i]) > -1;
}

for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j ++) {

    if (array[j].some(functionName)) {
        makeSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need just to declare the function outside the for loop , then call it inside the loop as guest

Comment: Why not give the code instead of just describing?!