# Why does. this arrow function not return an error?

Tags: javascript

In this function the cm variable has no data type eg var const or let. How does it still work without giving me an error?

```
          const inchToCm = inch => cm = inch * 2.54;
```

Is it because it used an implicit return?

Comment: it's just like if you had `function inchToCm(inch) { return cm = inch * 2.54; }` - does that help? i.e. `cm` will be a property on the global object (i.e. `window.cm` in a browser)

Comment: Also if you declare a variable without using a keyword, the variable will be global variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword