# calling a function in for loop giving infinite loop but same works fine in while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So i was working on a function which takes anything as argument and console logs it inside a box or a cell. This is what i came up with:

```
var horiz='━';
var vert='┃';
var ulcor='┏';
var urcor='┓';
var blcor='┗';
var brcor='┛';

//create a cell/box
var cell=(d='')=>{
    let h='';
    if(d==undefined||d==null){
        throw('cell needs an argument');
    }
    len=d.toString().length;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(i==0){
            for(j=0;j<len;j++){
                h+=horiz;
            }
            if(i==0) console.log(ulcor+h+urcor);
        }
        if(i==1){
            console.log(`${vert}${d}${vert}`);
        }
        if(i==2){
           console.log(blcor+h+brcor);    
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i was testing this i did following

```
cell('index');
cell(1);
```

gave following output:

```
┏━━━━━┓
┃index┃
┗━━━━━┛
┏━┓
┃1┃
┗━┛
```

and did other testing as well and it worked pretty well until i did the following test:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   cell(i)
}
```

Above code should give me cells/boxes with `1,2,3,4` but instead this gave me an infinite loop and what i noticed is that its only printing cells with 4 (not 1,2 or 3) but infinite times.

And now here is the fun part. When I do following:

```
n=1;
while(n<10){
  cell(n);
  n+=1;
}
```

above code gives desired result and works fine. 
Weird!! just Couldn't figure out why its running infinite times when i used it in the `for loop` but `while loop` works good. If any sort of improvement required in the code then please do mention it:)

Comment: Your re using the global variable `i` in the for loop version.

Comment: Variables in JS should always be defined with **let** or **const**. Especially in a for-loop `for (let i = 0; ...`

Comment: Run your code in strict mode and it should tell you about the coding problem you have.  If you don't know about strict mode, [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) about it.  Your code is running in "sloppy mode" and you're paying the price for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable without the `var`, `let`, or `const` keywords, that variable is an [implicit global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword). In your `cell` function, you use `for(i=0;i<3;i++)` where `i` is declared without a keyword.

Your calling for loop `for(i=0;i<5;i++){ cell(i) }` also uses `i` without a keyword which makes `i` refer to the same global variable. So your `call` function is actually manipulating `i` from within the function which makes the for loop behave in the unintended manner. The while loop uses a different variable, `n`, which is why it doesn't have the same problem.

Try changing the for loop inside `call` to `for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)` to limit the scope of `i`. And, in general, use [`let` and `const` to declare ALL variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var), even (and especially) the ones in for loops.